# How can i use timepicker in angular schema forms

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, angular-schema-form

I am using angular schema forms

https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/tree/master

There is a addon for datepicker

https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form-datepicker

But it does not support timepicker.

How can i add the timepicker or datetime pickers there

Date is working fine with this

```
scope.schema = {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "birthDate": {
      "title": "Bday",
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date"
    }
```

}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to, you could extend schema-forms.  They provide pretty detailed [**documentation**](https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/extending.md) on how to do so.

You can try to use one that has already been built though.  schema-form keeps a directory of 3rd party additions to schema-form [**here**](http://textalk.github.io/angular-schema-form/#/third-party-addons).

[**This**](https://github.com/networknt/angular-schema-form-datetimepicker) date-time-picker is available.

`"type": "string" and "format": "datetimepicker"`

Options:
    {
      "key": "publish_at",
      "options": {
        "minDate": new Date(),
        "minuteStep": 15,
        "autoclose": 1
      }
    },

Comment: but how can i integrate with schema forms

Comment: thanks for that , the problem is that depend on angular strap and i am using angular ui bootstrap. so they are not working together

Comment: Yes, I see that one is angular strap.  Just extend the u-bootstrap one then.  If you compare the docs for extending with the angular strap one, it looks pretty easy to do:
https://github.com/networknt/angular-schema-form-datetimepicker/blob/master/src/schema-form-datetimepicker.js

Install the ui-bootstrap one and create your extension module.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the devs at textalk that work on Angular Schema Form. The [datepicker addon](https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form-datepicker) is built on pickadate.js. Pickadate does as you know support a timepicker but we had no need for it.

Your option is to either modify the datepicker addon to use the timepicker as well or to create a new addon as tpie mentioned above and the documentation [is here](https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/extending.md).

As to how to use addons? There are usually detailed explanations in the readme on how to load the files and what the schema/form should look like to use it. Not all third parties write it but all ours have detailed instructions.

Comment: thanks for that. i did not get one thing. date and time picker is almost needed in every application. why they did not put it main application

Comment: @user3214546 I don't agree with this statement. None of our applications required time input. Most applications i know only specify date, not time. Another consideration was that the time input in pickadate is kinda clunky.

Comment: @Dervisevic no chance of the timepicker being supported as well at all?